# Why docker containers can run, despite of docker-machine is not running?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Apparently, this is a silly question, though, i hope someone can help me.

I was thinking docker containers can run, because docker-machine is running on my MacOS X. Like on this situation:

```
 > docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.2 

 > docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
abb8beb2a0fd        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"   48 minutes ago      Up 47 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   romantic_kare
```

But container can run, although in this situation.

```
 > docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown   

 > docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
abb8beb2a0fd        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"   48 minutes ago      Up 47 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   romantic_kare
```

Are there are no relationships between them?

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

---

I installed [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).

```
 > docker --version
Docker version 1.12.1, build 6f9534c
```

---

This post is duplicated with [Default docker machine on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193757/default-docker-machine-on-mac).

Comment: Do you also have Docker for Mac installed?

Comment: What version of docker are you using?
If it's <1.12 then docker-machine is no longer used for running images, they run natively on your windows/mac machine instead.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yes, i installed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default docker machine on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193757/default-docker-machine-on-mac). Not exact duplicate, but essentially the same issue. Docker for Mac supersedes boot2docker and the Virtualbox VM it used before.

Comment: @YaronIdan It's 1.12.1. Thank you for your advice. Now i understand why docker-machine is unnecessary.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I read it and you're right. My post is duplicated. And its answer is same with YaronIdan's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker 1.12 and onward no longer uses docker-machine to run containers. Instead it uses a native docker engine for mac/windows.